# Replace first occurrence of text using replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to replace the first occurrence of a paragraph in Google Doc using the function `replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)`, but I can't seem to find the right RegEx expression.
If someone could help me I would really appreciate it.

```
body.replaceText("^"+paragraph.getText()+"$"," ");
```

Comment: What is the text you wanted to replace and to what text you want to replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body.ReplaceText() function replaces all instances of a pattern, not just the first instance ( [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body%23replaceText(String,String)) ).

A better option may be to loop through the paragraphs to find the first with matching text, like so:

```
function deleteParagraph(textToRemove) {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 // gets all paragraphs as an array
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs()
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
    if (paragraphs[i].getText() === textToRemove){
      paragraphs[i].clear()
      Logger.log(textToRemove + " was removed")
      //stops it looping through any more paragraphs
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to practice with regular expressions then www.regexr.com is very handy.