# Google App Script replaceText to replace only first occurrence of matched string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I would like to use google appscript to replace text on my google doc to convert it to PDF. But the problem is the function replaceText(textToReplace, newText); just remove every occurrence of the matched text. I just want to remove only the first occurrence. How to do that?

Comment: Have you considered creating your own [search function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)? If a function doesn't come readymade, why not try to create it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace first occurrence of text using replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105989/replace-first-occurrence-of-text-using-replacetextsearchpattern-replacement)

Answer (score 6):

The `replaceText` method can be limited in scope to an element, by calling it on that element. But that does not help if the first paragraph where the text is found contains multiple instances of it: they are all going to be replaced.

Instead, use `findText` to find the first match, and then call `deleteText` and `insertText` to execute replacement.

```
// replaces the first occurrence of old
function replaceFirst(old, replacement) {    
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var found = body.findText(old);
  if (found) {
    var start = found.getStartOffset();
    var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    var text = found.getElement().asText();
    text.deleteText(start, end);
    text.insertText(start, replacement);
  }
}
```

If you think this ought to be easier, you are not alone.

Comment: There are dozens of us... dozens!

Comment: A slight modification to retain text formatting, I swapped the order the last tow lines for delete/insert text. This append the new text, then delete the original text: `text.insertText(end + 1, replacement); text.deleteText(start, end);`