# How to transfer one column of google sheet into google docs on particular places?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have cities of London on google sheet and I want to take one column which named cities with postcodes to the google doc on particular places. [I want that data to put into google doc that is shared in picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZnxU.png)

[That cities with postcode whole data into city name in google docs one by one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8arKL.png)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and [ask].

Comment: I will read that definately. But as a new member, you learn from your failures.

Comment: Please show what you have learned by editing the question to make it  a good fit for this site.

Comment: Have tried the suggested solution?

Comment: The question looks abandoned. No any reaction from the asker for several days. Vote to close

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = 'D5:D9'; // <--- set your range
  var cities = sheet.getRange(range).getValues().flat(); 
  var placeholder = '\\[bold\\]city name\\[/bold\\]';

  var doc_ID = '###'; // <--- set ID of your document
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(doc_ID);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  while (cities.length) {
    var find = body.findText(placeholder);
    if (!find) break;
    var city = '[bold]' + cities.shift() + '[/bold]';
    find.getElement().asText().replaceText(placeholder, city);
  }
}
```

This function takes list of city names form the range `D5:D9` of current sheet, opens a document with given ID and changes the placeholders `[bold]city name[/bold]` with the city names.

It works fine if there is only one placeholder per paragraph. If a paragraph can contain two or more placeholders (for different cities) it needs another implementation.

Here is the variant that handles several placeholders within a paragraph:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = 'D5:D9'; // <--- set your range
  var cities = sheet.getRange(range).getValues().flat(); 
  var placeholder = '\\[bold\\]city name\\[/bold\\]';

  var doc_ID = '###'; // set ID of your document
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(doc_ID);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783382
  var found = body.findText(placeholder);
  while (found) {
    if (cities.length == 0) break;
    var city = '[bold]' + cities.shift() + '[/bold]';
    var start = found.getStartOffset();
    var end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    var text = found.getElement().asText();
    text.insertText(end + 1, city);
    text.deleteText(start, end);
    found = body.findText(placeholder, found);
  }
}
```

It should keep all font styles but it doesn't sometimes.